# How to create a PR (pull request) on github using VSCODE editor

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-branch, pull-request

I have a branch `feature-atm` where i make changes not reflected on `main` branch. I try to keep my `feature-atm` branch in sync with the main branch by following the below steps ->

```
In visual studio code, use source control icon -> click Pull from -> click the repository path -> click master branch name.

At bottom of the visual studio code click on sync option to pull and push changes to feature branch.

This will update feature branch with master branch code.
```

The `main` branch has protection rules where is requires a PR# to be raised and get it approved from approves before my changes from `feature-atm` are reflected to `main`

How do I raise this PR# and the the PR number in vscode (preferably using UI) so that my changes from `feature-atm` are reflected on `main` branch one the PR#(pull request number) is approved by an approver.